# How to Get Image from a SOAP Web Service

Tags: java, web-services, soap, wsdl

My Client will give me WSDL url which will return a **JPEG Image** and some text.

i haven't got the WSDL yet so i was wondering that How i will be getting image in SOAP Message??

```
<?xml version="1.0"?> 
<soap:Envelope></soap:Envelope>
<soap:Body>
**??**
</soap:Body>
```

Note the **Question marks** in SOAP Body.
in which **Tag / Format** i will be getting the Image?

and after getting the image what **datatype of Java** i should use to set it in a **POJO**?

A bit Explanation or any Relevant Tutorail will be really helpfull..

Comment: you will likely need to use soap with attachments. the JPEG image will not be in the soap Body but it will be in the soap AttachmentPart. You will need to set the content type of the AttachmentPart and then read/write the content.

Comment: Fine i quite get it..
so What DataType of Java i should use to Get this Attachment part??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The service response may contain a picture as base64 or an attachment outside the envelope.
Example decoding base64:

```
public static BufferedImage decodeToImage(String imageString) {

    BufferedImage image = null;
    byte[] imageByte;
    try {
        BASE64Decoder decoder = new BASE64Decoder();
        imageByte = decoder.decodeBuffer(imageString);
        ByteArrayInputStream bis = new ByteArrayInputStream(imageByte);
        image = ImageIO.read(bis);
        bis.close();
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return image;
}
```

JAVA already has an API for processing [SOAP with attachments](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SOAP_with_Attachments_API_for_Java).

```
    SOAPMessage response = connection.call(requestMessage, serviceURL);
    Iterator attachmentsIterator = response.getAttachments();
    while (attachmentsIterator.hasNext()) {
        AttachmentPart attachment = (AttachmentPart) attachmentsIterator.next();
        //do something with attachment 
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

I hope this link will help you.. 
   http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/xml/library/x-tippass/

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/"
              xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
              xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
<soapenv:Body>
<ps:retrieve 
       soapenv:encodingStyle="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/encoding/"
       xmlns:ps="http://psol.com/2004/ws/retrieve">
<address xsi:type="xsd:base64Binary">d3d3Lm1hcmNoYWwuY29t</address>
</ps:retrieve>
</soapenv:Body>
</soapenv:Envelope>
```

Answer (score 0):

I use base64binary for send document, jpg etc.

```
<soap:element name="jpg" type="xs:base64Binary" minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="1"/>
```